# how the best form to put label top on input text css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started studying css and html and this doubt arose as to how it would be the best practice to position a label on top of an inputtext,

I did it that way

```html
<p style = {{flexDirection: 'column', display:'flex'}}>  
                        <p style = {{flexDirection: 'column', display:'flex'}}>
                            <label> Nome Fantasia </label>
                            <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Digite o Nome Fantasia'></input>
                        </p>
                        <p  style = {{flexDirection: 'column', display:'flex'}} > 
                            <label> Razão Social</label>
                            <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Digite a Razão Social'></input>
                        </p>
                    </p>
                    <p style = {{flexDirection:'row', display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}> 
                        <p style = {{flexDirection:'column', display:'flex'}}>
                            <label> CNPJ </label>
                            <input style = {{width:'100%'}} placeholder = 'Digite o CNPJ da empresa'></input>
                        </p>
                        <p style = {{flexDirection:'column', display:'flex'}}>
                            <label> Inscrição estadual </label>
                            <input placeholder = 'Digite sua inscrição estadual'></input>
                        </p>
                    </p>
                    <p style = {{flexDirection:'column', display:'flex'}}>
                        <p>
                            <p style = {{flexDirection:'column', display:'flex'}} >
                                <label> Telefone </label>
                                <input type = 'text' placeholder= 'Telefone'></input>
                            </p>
                            <p style = {{flexDirection:'column', display:'flex'}} >
                                <label> Email </label>
                                <input type = 'text' placeholder= 'Email'></input>
                            </p>
                        </p>
                    </p>
```

The result

[image]

there is another more practical and less verbose way to place inputtext next to each other and under the textlabel, how would you do it

Comment: https://codepen.io/nickhaskell/pen/HoGsm

Comment: I would try posting at (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) since your code is very simple as it is and it is working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the code is working but should probably be moved to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @imvain2 While this may be on-topic on CR in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `for` attribute

Html:

```
<p style = {{flexDirection: 'column', display:'flex'}}>
  <label for="nomeFantasia"> Nome Fantasia </label>
  <input type = 'text' id="nomeFantasia" placeholder = 'Digite o Nome Fantasia'>/input>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
label {display:block;}
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/buzztnt/pen/bGEEOdJ

MDN article on  : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label